# What is the best way to bypass devise authorization for a specific record marked public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I'm using devise and cancan in a Rails 3.2 project. I have an **event** model with a
boolean flag **public**. If the event is marked as **public => true** then I want anybody, signed in or not to be able to access the record with

```
GET /events/:id
```

If it is marked as **public => false** then a series of cancan abilities will decide authorization and access to the above resource.

What is the best pattern for achieving this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do that by skip the authenticate_user! in case of you have this args

```
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show, :if => lambda { 
    if params[:id]
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      @event and @event.public?
    else
      false
    end
  }
```

Comment: Actually the parameter is a field in the resource but now I think of it of course I can load the resource in the lambda and check the field.

Comment: The params[:id] is the resource identifier and if the resource is marked public then authentication is not needed. Can you suggest another method?

Comment: This solution seems to be deprecated. Check this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9703.

Answer (score -2):

No, do not skip authentication. You want to skip *authorization*. A better solution would be to explicitly authorize events with public => true.

In your cancan ability class:

```
can :read, Event do |e|
  some_other_authorization_boolean || e.public?
end
```

This ability would be given to all users; even ones that are not logged in.

Comment: If you don't skip authentication then you get thrown back out to the sign up screen. CANCAN authorization only occurs **after** devise authentication has had a chance to cancel the filter chain.